# What is the best way for allowing for dynamic object creation and removal in a Plotly Dash dashboard?

Tags: python, flask, callback, dashboard, plotly-dash

Currently, I have a class which stores a dictionary of Card elements, each of which is unique. The class can also generate these cards and append them to the dictionary or remove a card from a dictionary. However, I am not sure how to best allow for this action through a callback function since the ID for a card doesn't exist until the card is made, and the functionality isn't directly within the Dash framework since a dictionary object acts as an intermediary where the objects are stored.

Basically, I am wondering what the best way to dynamically create and destroy objects with a callback is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to avoid extra computation for building cards you wont use, I'd suggest create a which creates each card and store those functions in a dictionary. *(You can also create a universal function with params that allow specificity)*

```
my_card_functions = {
  'id_1': make_id_1,
  'id_2': make_id_2,
}
```

Creating a card could be done as such:

```
my_id = 'id_1'
f = my_card_functions[my_id] # will break if id isn't registered
my_card = f()
```

You can store the cards you want to create in a [dcc.store](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/store) object. Here's an example of some code you might consider:

```
# Pretend these are structured properly
dcc.Store(id='cards_data')
html.Div(id='my_cards',children=[])

@app.callback(
  Output('my_cards','children'),
  [Input('cards_data','data')],
  [State('my_cards','children')]
)
def make_cards(data, children):
  """Makes cards for each id"""
  if not data:
    raise PreventUpdate

  # The following code is not correct but serves as a demonstrative example
  # Some data structure manipulation is necessary to access 
  # the ids from the children elements
  children_ids = [x['id'] for x in children]

  # Assuming your data looks something like this:
  # {'add':['id_1','id_2']}

  for x in data['add']:
    if x not in children_ids:
      f = my_card_functions[my_id]
      my_card = f()

      # Store values
      children.append(my_card)

  return children
```

Note, this approach does not resolve removal of cards. That could easily be done but would probably require a more dynamic use of caching.

Comment: My approach was slightly different than this but your suggestion of using the dcc.Store element was great, as that way I can store things in an object that is accessible with a callback directly. But I basically have the functionality split between adding and removing cards in one callback, which adds a card if the id isn't there already, and vice versa. Then another one watches State like you have and iterates over the entire list and either retrieves from a cache or makes the card that needs to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the basis of your question, I have some immediate suggestions (since there is no working code that you have posted). 
1. Generate all card elements by default. They can be generated, but not 'displayed'
2. Add your callbacks to toggle the display/rendering of the cards dynamically based on the use case. That way you will have card element ids to play around with in the callbacks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was specifically trying to avoid this as I am talking about a huge number (10k+) of potential objects, each of which opens a request to an API as well, so this approach was simply impractical. Using cacheing on the requests was even unpractical as the API needs to be called at least once a day.